# Vertical circular motion inside a tube and with a light rod

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

I have a doubt that when the initial velocity given to a mass connected to a light rod fixed at one point, is $\sqrt{4gr}$   (given at the lowest point) then does it complete a circle or just reach the top and stop?
Also what will be the case of it was travelling in tube with just a little thickness so that the mass can fall onto the lower surface of the tube and continue the circular motion.
[image]

Comment: I think a picture to refer would be nice

Comment: I believe you need a > in front for it to continue past the top.

Comment: thank you all
may god bless you

Comment: i think adrian howard is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocity $\sqrt {4gr}$ is just enough to make it go to the top and stop. Any greater initial velocity would cause complete circular motion.

I don't think there would be any difference in the second case, as its not going to gain any tangential velocity after falling down. The critical velocity remains $\sqrt {4gr}$.